# How to use worker role in web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-worker-roles

I have created cloud worker role using VS2013.I have a web application (ASP.net and C#) separatly.I am going to host both applications on azure server.How To integrate worker role with web application?

Comment: This is a very vague question, what do you mean by integrate worker role with web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am going to host both applications on azure server.

Azure Cloud Service could be a choice for you. [Azure Cloud Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-choose-me) provides two types of roles: Web role and Worker role, you can serve your web application on Web role.

Besides, if you’d like to host your web application on [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-overview), you can try to implement same functionalities as your worker role in a [WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs), and run WebJob in your Azure App Service web app.

For more information about hosting options that Azure provides, you can refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm).